# Android Listview - only load images into items when user stops scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

When the user scrolls quickly through items, it seems superfluous to start requesting images to populate those items. Afterall, the user is scrolling so fast, they will never be downloaded/shown in time. Is there any kind of method/event that first fires when the user has actually paused scrolling?

Comment: have you get solved your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to detect scrolling stop :

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
{
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(scrollState == 0) 
            Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out (upvoted for now) - I guess I will need to track if user starts to scroll again, and if still within the item! Otherwise it looks like what I need.