# listview header with large image

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview which headerView has a large image. When I call

```
listView.addHeaderView(headerView)
```

my listview doesn't scroll smoothly when I remove it it start scroll fine.

I am using Aquery lib for downloading image and cashing image

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(img);
        aq.id(R.id.image).image(mProduct.getMobile_pic(), true, true, mActivity.getCurrentDeviceDisplayMatrics().widthPixels, 0, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){

            @Override
            public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap loadedImage, AjaxStatus status){
                iv.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            }

        });
```

first true value is turn on memory cache, second is disk cache.

What possible reason could prevent smooth scroll of listview?

Comment: What worked for me: wait for the user to stop scrolling and then load the image.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean @Mdlc

Comment: Ok, wait for the user to stop scrolling, then load the images. So you can prevent lag during the scrolling as there are no images being loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826465/android-listview-only-load-images-into-items-when-user-stops-scrolling